# complex types in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I need to describe in my interface a string with indexes also in the end of string can be work or crash:

```
export interface Test {
    date: string,
   'stat.conv[index: number].key[index: number].(work || crash)': Test2[]
}
```

Is this possible in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to define the keys:

```
export interface Test {
    date: string;
   [key: `stat.conv[${number}].key[${number}].${'work'| 'crash'}`]: any;
}

const t: Test = {
  date: '',
  'stat.conv[0].key[0].work': '', // OK
  'stat.conv[1].key[1].crash': '', // OK
  'stat.conv[x].key[y].work': '', // Error
  'stat.conv[0].key[0].nothing': '' // Error
}
```